# Obtain substring in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have to obtain the substring in a string without giving position using SQL in PostgreSQL.

I have tried in this way but which is displaying only last number '2'

This way i have worked 
The String is P1.B1.12

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REGISTRATIONNO from '.(.)*') AS REGISTRATIONNO 
FROM SUBSCRIBER;
```

The expected result is `12` - everything after the second `.`

Comment: And what is the desired result? Which substring do you want to get from the value `P1.B1.12`

Comment: yep i want get the all string after second "."

Comment: Is it the value after the second `.` or is it the "last" value of a "dot delimited" string? What should the result from `P1.B1.C1.14` be?

Comment: after second digit it contains only numbers.

Comment: no more dots will appear after second dot. for example p1.b1.1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (regexp_split_to_array(registrationno, '\.'))[3]
from subscriber
```

Note that this assumes that the desired value is *always* at the third position. If this is not the case, the expression will return the wrong value.

Here is an SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1924

Comment: Finally i have got solution. Thank you so much for your pretty answer. .

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REGISTRATIONNO from '\w*.\w*.(\d+)') AS REGISTRATIONNO 
FROM SUBSCRIBER;
```

Comment: yep but it is not working.:( i want to get all the contents after second "." in a string.

Comment: I modified a bit the regexp. Can you try again?

Comment: Hello Lajos Veres, String would be anything for example: abcd.hi.1245 but after second "." no more dots ill appeat its only number .

Comment: Thanks for Response @  Lajos Veres

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REGISTRATIONNO, '.', -1) AS REGISTRATIONNO 
FROM SUBSCRIBER;
```

Comment: There is no `substring_index` function in Postgres